# Where do you specify urls in a spring mvc project?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If we are calling an internal service we would look up its address from a service registry. But what if the service we are calling is external like some google api. What is the right place to declare the url? In the .net world we would define it in web.config but not sure what would be a good place to declare it in spring mvc.

Comment: if it is not spring boot then you can use use any .properties file, else in the case you may use application.properties to hold such variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring Framework

Good place to define all your static URLs would be in `*.properties` file.

Default one is `application.properties`

This file will be added in `src/main/resources` folder of project